# How to `lockscaleX` and `lockscaleY` but allow `uniscaling` the object in Fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

How to `lockscaleX` and `lockscaleY` but allow `uniscaling` the object in Fabric.js? Here is what I tried:

```
if (shape.scaleX != 1 && shape.scaleY != 1) {
                    shape.width = shape.scaleX * shape.width;
                    shape.height = shape.scaleY * shape.height;
                    shape.scaleX = 1;
                    shape.scaleY = 1;
                } else {
                    shape.scaleX = 1;
                    shape.scaleY = 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's easy:

```
object.lockUniScaling = true;
```